# cannot convert from 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream' to 'Windows.Storage.IStorageFile'

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have document (.doc) stored in IsolatedStorage of my application. I need to open that document in Office application.

After quite long search I coded like below. But it shows error. I need to know How to convert IsolatedStorageFileStream to IStorageFile.

Here's my code:

```
var file = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(sFile, FileMode.Open, myFile);
await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Myself found an answer:

```
var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(sFile);
await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
```